# What is the best way to start thin in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, thin

You can start the thin server by one of the following ways:

- `thin start`
- `rails s` (if you have thin in the `Gemfile`)

Is there any difference on performance/compatibility between these two ways, or the `rails s` actually only calls `thin start`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that they are both functionally equivalent. However, adding thin to your `Gemfile` will only start thin automatically if you are using rails >= 3.2. Otherwise, you will have to start thin by passing `rails server thin` at the command line.

```
$ thin start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Notice the difference between `thin start` and `rails server` if rails >= 3.2  or `rails server thin`

```
$ rails server thin
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

It prints out more info about the rails environment. It seems that sticking to the `rails server` convention would be the wise thing to do. Although I haven't seen anything different between the two ways of starting thin, I would stick with the conventional `rails server`